# Remove duplicates with drupal recurring dates in view

Tags: date, drupal, view, duplicates

I have a content type called Event which has a field called field_event_date. The date field can have recurring dates. I'm trying to display a list of events and only show each event one time, however it is showing once for each of the recurring dates.

I've found many posts about this and still can't figure it out.

My view is very simple. It is showing fields and I've tried grouping them by title or nid, but neither changes the number of results. I've also tried checking Distinct (and Pure Distinct) under Query Settings. But nothing changes the number of results returned.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use under field configuration the "**Start date only**" and "**Show 1 value**" as seen in the screenshot below. No need for aggregation and distinct settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Apply a filter on the date field
- Select the operator: 'Is equal to', and type '0'

> When you have a multiple value field, the field has a list or array of values. delta=0 is the first value

https://www.drupal.org/node/1872262#comment-6869736